# Change storage on KVM

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm

I have virtual machine in KVM "machine01" I have storage on it `/data/sas1/virt/virt.qcow2` and not used `/data/sas1/virt/virt2.qcow2`

I want to change via command line on my supervisor from `/data/sas1/virt/virt.qcow2` to `/data/sas1/virt/virt2.qcow2` my VirtIO Disk source path. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this while the guest is running I know of no way to do it except possibly through migration.

On the other hand, if you can switch your guest off and you're using `libvirt` to manage it you can use `virsh`. Its man page even has an example for this scenario:

```
virsh dumpxml machine01 > machine01.xml
vi machine01.xml    # or make changes with your other text editor such as sed
virsh create machine01.xml
```